# Collection of simple functions is an algebra

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Define $\mathcal{A} = \{f:f \hspace{2mm} \mbox{is a simple function}\}$. This collection forms an algebra and I have some questions about how this actually works.

Let $A \in \mathcal{A}$. Since $f$ is a simple function it has canonical representation $f(x) = \sum_{j=1}^{n} a_j \chi_{A_j}(x)$ where $a_j \in \mathbb{R}$ and $A_j \in \mathcal{A} \forall j$. This would be the setup for the idea of the collection of simple functions. Now if $A \in \mathcal{A}$, then $A=f(x) =\sum_{j=1}^{n} a_j \chi_{A_j}(x)$. The first property requires that $A^c \in \mathcal{A}$ as well, but this doesn't really make sense, and so I think I have the wrong idea here. Where am I going wrong, or have I just not taken the problem far enough? I feel like for $A \in \mathcal{A}$ it should affect the characteristic function,  but that is only my intuition.

Comment: i think you have the wrong definition of an algebra

Comment: 'algebra' is used in an 'algebraic sense' here. It has nothing to with an algerba of sets.

Comment: I'm using the definition that for all $A,B \in \mathcal{A}$ that $A^c \in \mathcal{A}$ and $A \cup B \in \mathcal{A}$. This is coming from an analysis practice test, so I'm not sure what you mean? The question states "Show the collection of all simple functions forms an algebra"

Comment: Algebra is presumably meant in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_over_a_field#Definition) sense. Where $+$ is pointwise addition of functions and $\cdot$ pointwise multiplication. It is (presumably) not about $\sigma$-Algebras.

Comment: OH, well my professor did not make that clear at all, that does seem odd as he has never made that issue before, but that makes way more sense. Thank you